# browsing folders in a folder

Tags: java, subdirectory, folderbrowserdialog

I want to open a folder which has multiple sub-folders in it. Each sub-folder has some files.
I want to open a specific file number(lets say 3rd file in each folder) and manipulate it. Can someone help, since I am not able to figure it out from other threads.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: isDirectory() function to check for subdirectories... and listFiles() to get list of all files ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the code below, it recursively iterates over the contents of the folder and lets you read/manipulate the 3rd file-

```
public void openAndManipulateFile(final File root) {

    // get the list of files/folders
    final File[] files = root.listFiles();
    int counter = 0;

    for (File file : files) {

        // if its a directory, read its contents
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            // recursive method call
            openAndManipulateFile(file);
        } else {
            if (++counter == 3) {
                // open and manipulate the 3rd file
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To call it -

```
    File rootFolder = new File("some folder");
    openAndManipulateFile(rootFolder);
```

Comment: +1, thats look like a good answer. but please check this out http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272.

Comment: Hi, thanks. What do you mean when you say "To call it"?-does it mean to open the file and use it?

Comment: To initiate the process, you can pass the base folder to that method.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to read all files from a directory

```
File folder = new File("/Users/you/folder/");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

Iterate over the listOfFiles and check with isDirectory() if the item is a directory. If yes you can use the same procedure to look into the sub-folders.